# File is not recognized after generating the ".APK" file from Go to Android using gomobile tool

Tags: android, android-studio, go, gomobile

I am working on a project in which i need to generate an APK file form a Golang code base using [gomobile](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile) tool.
the plan is to be able to run it on android tablet.
When I install the apk file on the tablet, through the Android Studio I get the following error.

```
 E/Go: panic: open C:/Users/ash/OneDrive/Desktop/go-workSpace/src/Myproject/config.json: no such file or directory
```

However, after clicking on the given path in the error message, the Android Studio opens the the file it is complaining to find (config.json)

Here is the source code I have in Go

```
exDir := "C:/Users/ash/OneDrive/Desktop/go-workSpace/src/Myproject/"    
configFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join(filepath.Dir(exDir), "config.json")) // Look for the config file in the same directory as the executable
    
Check(err)

func Check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Received generic error, panicking")
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Any suggestion how to fix the file path?

Comment: Consider this: do you think every single tablet to install the app will have `C:/Users/ash/OneDrive/Desktop/go-workSpace/src/Myproject/config.json` on its filesystem? Probably not... Perhaps you actually want to use an [asset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418556/6069012).

Comment: @Gavin Thanks for your comment. Yes, this is for testing. 
I should definitely use some standard utilities to make it general for all the apps.
Just hard coded for now to find the root cause of app crashing.

Comment: My point is, your tablet likely does not have that path available (even though *your computer* does), which is why the application crashes but you can find the file.

Comment: Assuming you are turning your **config.json** file into a `map[string]string` or something similar, comment out that file read line and just hardcode the stuff in **config.json** inline and test out your code. That file path is a _Windows_ specific file path. Android is Linux based and there is no `C:` drive. Or you can copy **config.json** onto the tablet in a known location and put that path in the read line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412762/gomobile-how-to-embed-assets-in-apk).
Here is the official go support [page](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile/asset).
So, I think I need to

1. move all the files into a directory called **assets**.
2. The **assets** directory is embedding to the ".APK" can be accessed through Android code base.

> ```
> import "golang.org/x/mobile/asset"  
>
> jsonFile, errOpen := asset.Open(config.json)
> if errOpen != nil {
>     fmt.Println(errOpen)
> }
> defer jsonFile.Close()
> buf, errRead := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)
> if errRead != nil {
>     fmt.Println(errRead)
> }
> ```